# Routing multiple messages to same stream in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I came up with a scenario where I will create multiple XML messages and set them as part of the Exchange object.

In my router how can I route multiple message parts set in the exchange body to the same stream? Basically i have to send two different set of messages as a part of property to a MQ.

Processor Code

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
exchange.setProperty("msg1", xml1);
exchange.setProperty("msg2",xml2);
}
```

Router Code

```
@Override
    public void configure() {
from("solace:q")
.process(aboveProcessor)
..?//code to route both messages as two different messages to same MQ.
}
```

If there is some other approach I should use, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting Exchange Properties, which are not sent with JMS messages anyway, you could populate a list in your processor, setting the body to be the resultant list:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add( xml1 );
    list.add( xml2 );
    exchange.getIn().setBody( list );
}
```

and then split the list, before sending to your queue:

```
from("solace:q")
  .process(aboveProcessor)
  .split(body())
    .to("mq:myQueue");
```

This assumes you are sending each of your two XML documents to the same queue, and with the same message headers.

Comment: It is not allowed to use to("mq:myQueue") after split();
Should i use split(body()).to("mq:myQueue");

Comment: Yes - I think that will work fine. I’ll update my answer later.